# I get null fields Unmarshalling a xml with spring-oxm

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, gradle

I am coding a small command line tool to maintain a database. As an start point, I am reducing the problem to one table. Basically I perform CRUD operations over it. The input is an xml file. I have created a spring application, is the first time I use it out of a web application context. For building I am using gradle 1.11.

I have a test class. One of the tests is very simple: read a test xml file from the classpath and unmarshall it. This is the server.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs2:server xmlns:xs2="http://www.opsource.net/simpleapp">
    <xs2:id>5</xs2:id>
    <xs2:name>Server_5</xs2:name>
</xs2:server>
```

This is the method that unmarshalls the xml:

```
@Autowired
private Unmarshaller unMarshaller;

public ServerType unMarshallServerType(InputStream is) throws XmlMappingException, IOException{
    ServerType server = (ServerType) unMarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is));
    return server;
}
```

In the application context I defined my jaxb2Marshaller:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.mangrar.jaxb.ServerType</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have checked already that the content of the InputStream is right, and the Unmarshalling is not throwing any exception, but, the 2 properties inside the ServerType instance, are null. This is the ServerType class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "serverType", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "name"
})
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.opsource.net/simpleapp", name = "server" )
public class ServerType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String id;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
}
```

The weirdest thing is that if I run 'gradle test', the tests are working, but not with the IDE. I have tried with IDEA and Eclipse, latest versions, and still getting null. I have created a support request to Jetbrains, and for then, is not working with gradle either.

Any idea what it could be not working?

Answer (score 1):

You have only specified the namespace qualification for the root element. There are a couple ways that you can solve this problem.

### Option #1 - Everything in One Class

You can leverage the `namespace` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation as well as the one on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

**ServerType.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "serverType", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "name"
})
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.opsource.net/simpleapp", name = "server" )
public class ServerType {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.opsource.net/simpleapp", required = true)
    protected String id;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.opsource.net/simpleapp", required = true)
    protected String name;
}
```

### Option #2 - Specify the Namespace Qualification with `@XmlSchema`

**package-info.java**

When you specify the namespace qualification on the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = ""http://www.opsource.net/simpleapp",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**ServerType.java**

Then it will automatically be applied and you won't have to specify it on `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElement`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "serverType", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "name"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "server" )
public class ServerType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String id;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
}
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about JAXB and namespaces on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: It was that. I probably deleted the package-info.java by mistake. What I don´t get is why it was working from gradle. But anyway, I added the package-info.java and now is working. Thank you very much!!!!